# CMAKE aux_source_directory exclude pattern

Tags: cmake

I want to include all filed in source directory leaving one file.

Is there any way to using aux_source_directory or anything else I can include all files leaving that file ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two possible solutions:

Use `file (GLOB ...` instead of `aux_source_directory` with a globbing expression that does not match that one file but includes all the others, e.g.:

```
file(GLOB _srcFiles "src/f[1-3].cpp")
```

This will match match files `f1.cpp`, `f2.cpp`, `f3.cpp`, but not `f4.cpp`.

Or use `aux_source_directory` and then remove the file to be excluded explicitly with a `list(REMOVE_ITEM` command, e.g.:

```
aux_source_directory(src _srcFiles)
list(REMOVE_ITEM _srcFiles "src/f4.cpp")
```